# Formula Re-Calculates Entire Column

Tags: excel, excel-2010

I am having a problem with this formula. I am using to simply add the date in "Column A" when "Column B & C" are not blank. Seems to work fine, but each day it updates/calculates the previous dates in the entire column to today.  How do I prevent the previous dates from changing?

```
=IF(AND($B6100>"",$C6100>""),TODAY(),"")
```

Comment: Use VBA and not formulas.  Formulas are live and as the inputs change the outputs change.

Comment: As @ScottCraner implies, this is actually the way functions are designed to behave.  What you want is a calculation that fixes at calculation time, not one that is a real-time calculation.  You can export as a CSV which will export the values, not the formulas, or use VBA or some other calculation tool.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lets assume that the raw data is entered in **B2** through **C9999**.  Place the following event macro in the worksheet code area:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim rIn As Range, r As Long
    Set rIn = Range("B2:C9999")

    If Intersect(rIn, Target) Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
    If Target.Count > 1 Then Exit Sub
    r = Target.Row
    If Cells(r, 1) <> "" Then Exit Sub
    If Cells(r, 2) = "" Or Cells(r, 3) = "" Then Exit Sub

    Application.EnableEvents = False
        Cells(r, 1) = Date
    Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

Because it is worksheet code, it is very easy to install and automatic to use:

1. right-click the tab name near the bottom of the Excel window
2. select View Code - this brings up a VBE window
3. paste the stuff in and close the VBE window

If you have any concerns, first try it on a trial worksheet.

If you save the workbook, the macro will be saved with it.
If you are using a version of Excel later then 2003, you must save
the file as .xlsm rather than .xlsx

To remove the macro:

1. bring up the VBE windows as above
2. clear the code out
3. close the VBE window

To learn more about macros in general, see:

http://www.mvps.org/dmcritchie/excel/getstarted.htm

and

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee814735(v=office.14).aspx

To learn more about Event Macros (worksheet code), see:

http://www.mvps.org/dmcritchie/excel/event.htm

**Macros must be enabled for this to work!**

Comment: This is awesome!  Thank You @Gary's Student for your time and help. This works great.